# How do I split my screen to include a JFrame and a lwjgl screen

Tags: java, lwjgl, swing, jframe

I a making a game and I'm going to make a little side GUI to create game items.

How can I have a window both include a Canvas element and an lwjgl window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AWTGLCanvas](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/opengl/AWTGLCanvas.java) to host your LWJGL context inside your GUI.

For LWJGL3, There's this demo of putting a LWJGL context in a canvas in the source: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/samples/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/system/jawt/JAWTDemo.java

Comment: +1 thanks but can I use the java canvas method with lwjgl.

Comment: this is a Java canvas with LWJGL.